# SQLite running 'some' queries, under iOS9, views a lot slower than iOS8

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios9

Just starting to fully test our App with Xcode Version 7.0 (7A220). It makes heavy use of SQLite, lots of queries, inserts, updates and use of views, etc. It's a product-pricing tool and has lots of row iterations so it can pull offers and their various rules and dependancies. It does do a lot when asked. Under Xcode 6, supporting iOS8, performance was fine. Not a problem, instant. When the same App, actually compiled for iOS8, and already installed on the iPad before iOS9, is run, it runs like a snail on smack.

So it's definitely iOS9. That's the only thing that's different. So, back to Xcode 7, I start to debug. Where in the code, is it sticking or where is the performance being affected. I have isolated the sticking, slowness to a query. It's a view, a very complicated view, however, it ran very quickly on iOS8. It's fairly sizeable and I'll post it if asked, but my main question stands... is there anything I need to be aware of as regards iOS9 and SQLite performance? As it is, I'm baffled as to what the problem is. I tried removing the:

```
sqlite3.dylib
```

And replacing it with the library that appears to ship with Xcode 7:

```
libsqlite3.0.tbd
```

and then

```
libsqlite3.tbd
```

But neither helped.

Still running very slow.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Try the sqlite3.dylib that shipped with Xcode 6.4.

Comment: Can you post an Instruments trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK- thanks, for the above suggestions. I looked at an Instruments Trace, but this wasn't really necessary as debugging told me the exact query that was running slower.

But my question concerns why it is that **moving from iOS8 to iOS9** would cause the **query optimiser to evaluate the SAME query differently**. At it definitely did. For completeness, I'm answering this question myself as I have solved the issue. But, only in that I had to re-work the SQL a little to accommodate whatever the optimiser is now doing.

Interestingly, the same SQLite library, in use, has not changed. So, I'm still at a loss as to why a move to iOS9 would cause this problem for me. Below, the query. I would not expect anyone to understand it, suffice to say the syntax is understandable. But, the way I altered the query was to take out a SELECT, (or replace) from one of the nested selects.

It's almost as if SQLite does to like the depth of the nested queries under iOS9. Of course this makes no sense. But it's what I have observed.

```
NSString *view = @" CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS OFF_VIEW_5_FIXED_AMT_OFF AS "
        " SELECT OTV_OOL_OOH_SEQ_NO          AS R_OOL_OOH_SEQ_NO, "
        "        OTV_OOL_SEQ_NO              AS R_OOL_SEQ_NO, "
        "        OTV_OO_SEQ_NO               AS R_OO_SEQ_NO, "
        "        AMOUNT_DUE                  AS R_OOL_TOTAL_SAVINGS, "
        "        TOTAL_PAYABLE_WITHOUT_OFFER AS R_OOL_TOTAL_PAYABLE_NO_OFFER, "
        "        CASE "
        "          WHEN (100.00 / TOTAL_PAYABLE_WITHOUT_OFFER * AMOUNT_DUE) > 100.00 THEN "
        "            100.00 "
        "          ELSE "
        "           (100.00 / TOTAL_PAYABLE_WITHOUT_OFFER * AMOUNT_DUE) "
        "        END                         AS R_OOL_PICKED_PERC_OFF_ALL_ORD, "
        "        CASE "
        "          WHEN SUM(OFFER_PAYABLE_BY_LINE) < 0 THEN "
        "            0.00 "
        "          ELSE "
        "            SUM(OFFER_PAYABLE_BY_LINE) "
        "        END                         AS R_OFFER_TOTAL_PAYABLE_BY_LINE "
        "   FROM (SELECT OTV_OOL_SEQ_NO, "
        "                OTV_OO_SEQ_NO, "
        "                OTV_OOL_OOH_SEQ_NO, "
        "               (CASE "
        "                 WHEN OO_ORD_VAL_BASED_ON_PERC_YN = 'Y' THEN "
        "                   TOTAL_PAYABLE_WITHOUT_OFFER - (TOTAL_PAYABLE_WITHOUT_OFFER / 100.00 * ORDER_TOTAL_TRIGGER) "
        "                 ELSE "
        "                   CASE "
        "                     WHEN OO_DISCOUNT_ENTIRE_ORDER_YN = 'Y' THEN "
        "                       ORDER_TOTAL_TRIGGER " // -- * -1 -- When actioned, this needs to be taken off the order, perhaps defined as a negative amount.
        "                     ELSE "
        "                       TOTAL_PAYABLE_WITHOUT_OFFER - ORDER_TOTAL_TRIGGER "
        "                   END "
        "                END) * (100.00 / TOTAL_PAYABLE_WITHOUT_OFFER * OTV_OOL_UNIT_PRICE) / 100.00 AS OFFER_PAYABLE_BY_LINE, "
        "                TOTAL_PAYABLE_WITHOUT_OFFER, "
        "                ORDER_TOTAL_TRIGGER AS AMOUNT_DUE "

        "           FROM (SELECT OTV_OOL_SEQ_NO, "
        "                        OTV_OO_SEQ_NO, "
        "                        OTV_OO_OFFER_ID, "
        "                        OTV_OOL_OOH_SEQ_NO, "
        "                        OTV_OOL_UNIT_PRICE, "
        "                        TOTAL_PAYABLE_WITHOUT_OFFER, "
        "                        OO_ORD_VAL_BASED_ON_PERC_YN, "
        "                        OO_DISCOUNT_ENTIRE_ORDER_YN, "
        "                        OTV_TRIG_VAL_ON_ENTIRE_ORD_YN, "
        "                        TOTAL_SALES_VALUE_ALL_ORDER, "

        "                       (SELECT OAOBOV_AMOUNT_OFF "
        "                          FROM OFF_AMOUNT_OFF_BY_ORDER_VALUE "
        "                         WHERE OAOBOV_OO_SEQ_NO = OTV_OO_SEQ_NO "
        "                           AND OAOBOV_TRIGGER_VALUE = "

        "                            (SELECT MAX(OAOBOV_TRIGGER_VALUE) "
        "                               FROM OFF_AMOUNT_OFF_BY_ORDER_VALUE "
        "                              WHERE OAOBOV_TRIGGER_VALUE <= CASE "
        "                                      WHEN OTV_TRIG_VAL_ON_ENTIRE_ORD_YN = 'Y' THEN "
        "                                        TOTAL_SALES_VALUE_ALL_ORDER "
        "                                      ELSE "
        "                                        TOTAL_PAYABLE_WITHOUT_OFFER "
        "                                      END "
        "                                AND OAOBOV_OO_SEQ_NO = OTV_OO_SEQ_NO)) AS ORDER_TOTAL_TRIGGER "

        "                    FROM (SELECT OTV_OOL_SEQ_NO, "
        "                                 OTV_OO_OFFER_ID, "
        "                                 OTV_OO_SEQ_NO, "
        "                                 OTV_OOL_OOH_SEQ_NO, "
        "                                 OTV_OOL_UNIT_PRICE, "
        "                                 OO_ORD_VAL_BASED_ON_PERC_YN, "
        "                                 OO_DISCOUNT_ENTIRE_ORDER_YN, "
        "                                 OTV_TRIG_VAL_ON_ENTIRE_ORD_YN, "
        "                                (SELECT SUM(OTV_OOL_UNIT_PRICE) FROM OFF_TEMP_5) AS TOTAL_PAYABLE_WITHOUT_OFFER, "
        "                                 CASE "
        "                                   WHEN OTV_USE_ORD_VAL_AFTER_DISC_YN = 'Y' THEN "
        /*
         "                                     (SELECT SUM(OOL_PICKED_PRICE) "
         "                                        FROM OFF_ORDER_LINES "
         "                                       WHERE OOL_OOH_SEQ_NO = OTV_OOL_OOH_SEQ_NO "
         "                                         AND OOL_SEQ_NO NOT IN "
         "                                           (SELECT OOL_OOL_SEQ_NO "
         "                                              FROM OFF_CHOICE_LOCKED_CORES, "
         "                                                   OFF_ORDER_LINES "
         "                                             WHERE OCLC_OOH_SEQ_NO = OTV_OOL_OOH_SEQ_NO "
         "                                               AND OCLC_OOL_SEQ_NO = OOL_SEQ_NO "
         "                                               AND OOL_DISCOUNT_ENTIRE_ORDER_YN = 'N')) "
        */
        "                                     (SELECT OTAOV_AFTER_OFFER_ORDER_VALUE FROM OFF_TEMP_AFTER_OFFER_VALUE) "

        "                                   ELSE "
        "                                     (SELECT SUM(OOL_UNIT_PRICE * OOL_QTY) "
        "                                        FROM OFF_ORDER_LINES OOL "
        "                                       WHERE OOL_OOH_SEQ_NO = OTV_OOL_OOH_SEQ_NO "
        "                                         AND OOL.OOL_LINE_TYPE_ID = 'S') "
        "                                 END                                             AS TOTAL_SALES_VALUE_ALL_ORDER "
        "                           FROM OFF_TEMP_5)) "
        "                   WHERE ORDER_TOTAL_TRIGGER IS NOT NULL) "

        "        GROUP BY OTV_OOL_OOH_SEQ_NO, "
        "                 OTV_OOL_SEQ_NO, "
        "                 AMOUNT_DUE, "
        "                 TOTAL_PAYABLE_WITHOUT_OFFER, "
        "                 OTV_OO_SEQ_NO ";
```

So, the greyed out section between /* and */ is what I took out.

And this...

```
(SELECT OTAOV_AFTER_OFFER_ORDER_VALUE FROM OFF_TEMP_AFTER_OFFER_VALUE)
```

... is what I replaced it with. Before I run the view, I insert one row into the above table, one row, one column and then select from it. So in essence, I'm removing the need to run the query in quotes.

So, I guess at the end of all of this, for anyone experiencing a similar issue, mine was down to query complexity. But I remain confused as to why it was totally fine on iOS8, Xcode 6.x.

Maybe it'll help someone else.